# Getting Null Pointer while getting project Name in CI testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getName();

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, soapui

Getting null point exception when trying to get project name Working fine in soap UI but failing in Jenkins at Step //testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getName();

```
def ProjectName= testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getName();

def prj = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(ProjectName)

def TestCaseName = testRunner.testCase.getLabel()
def TestSuiteName = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getLabel()
tCase = prj.testSuites[TestSuiteName].testCases[TestCaseName]
tStep = tCase.getTestStepByName("[GET] Get Project By Project Id")
```

Comment: How are you running this in Jenkins? Command line, or Maven plugin?

Comment: command line in Jenkins

Comment: I'm out of ideas. But I don't get what you are trying to accomplish. You could replace that entire code sample with just `testRunner.testCase.testSteps['[GET] Get Project By Project Id']`.